# Data type used to store particular expression

Tags: c++, expression

This line of code wont work as intended, because the data type used to store the expression is integer, resulting in integer overflow in case of being greater than INT_MAX.
`if(y*10+modulo>INT_MAX) return 0;`

This other line executes perfectly when same edge case is encountered. Where y,j are integers, and a is a vector of integers. What data type is used to store this second expression?
`if( y+a[i]*pow(10,j)>INT_MAX) return 0;`

Additional context:
In both cases reversing an integer is attempted, a[i] storing the digits of input number in reverse order, and j starting from size of a -1

To avoid confusion about the -1, a 3 digit number ex 123 can be written like this 1 * 10^2 + 2 * 10^1 + 3*10^0

I tried the first two things you do before coming here, asking google and ai about this case.

Comment: If all the terms involved in the expression is `int`s you might want to promote to `std::int64_t` before calculation to prevent overflow.

Comment: You can use `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(y+a[i]*pow(10,j)), double>);` to confirm the type. Using `pow` isn't the best idea, it operates on floating-point numbers and can be imprecise.

Comment: You've probably figured this out, but you should move everything that makes `y` bigger to the right side of `>` (e.g `y>INT_MAX/10-modulo`) to avoid overflow.

Comment: You can check `typeid(y+a[i]*pow(10,j)).name()` at runtime to answer the question _"what data type is used to store this?"_

Comment: I mistakenly thought that you can not do this in c, also I couldn't answer on my own to the curious question why. These 2 lines seemed identical, though I knew they were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "secret" is the call to `pow`; despite being given integer arguments, it only has float-type variants (in this case, I believe it defaults to `double`). This causes the entire expression to use a floating-point type, which does have a larger range than `int`.

Comment: I did as HolyBlackCat suggested, and got no compilation error, which means the type is indeed double. 
Thanks to everyone who took their time to contemplate and answer to my question, and also explain further the answer